# Report delete option missing in salesforce lightning

Tags: community, managed-package, reporting, salesforce1-app

I installed a managed package in production environment and created some standard reports on an object(this object is part of managed package). After uninstallation of the same managed package, I found that the above report cannot be viewed as related object has been deleted as managed package was uninstalled, which totally makes sense. However, delete option also got removed from lightning environment for that report(see right side in below picture).

The same option is available in classic environment.
I also tried to replicate the same issue in other orgs like sandbox. But there it is working fine.

Can someone suggest what is wrong with lightning environment? All permissions regarding report are same in production and sandbox[image: delete option missing in report]

Comment: Can you please double check,if you have any dashboards created on this report.If yes,please delete the dashboards first and then you will be able to delete the Report.

Comment: You are right, A dashboard has been created on same. However it's client's org and I can't delete data from there. So i replicated the same scenario in my sandbox - a report with a dependent dashboard. There, the delete option is still visible. I am really confused on why the same option isn't visible in the prod org.

Comment: As mentioned in the below article you can’t delete reports in others’ personal folders.So,can you please check if the report is in someone's personal folder.https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_delete.htm&type=5

Comment: No, reports are in public folder.

Comment: Update - Raised the case with Salesforce team. They said it was a glitch that occurred during managed package uninstallation. Since the delete option is available in classic view, users deleted reports from there.